# posix timer_delete coredump

Tags: timer, posix

I nead to find a way to check if one posix timer exist in user mode.

I read manual page, and also read linux-kernel-posix code, but still can't find a way to do it.

I create a posix timer with 'timer_create'. 
Then I reload my process(timer destroyed?)，after that, 'timer_delete' will coredump.

backtrace as follow:

```
Program terminated with signal 11, Segmentation fault.
#0  __timer_delete_new (timerid=0x1edb770) at ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/timer_delete.c:40
40    int res = INLINE_SYSCALL (timer_delete, 1, kt->ktimerid);
```

Comment: How exactly do you _reload_ your process?

Answer (score 0):

> I create a posix timer with `timer_create`. Then I reload my process(timer destroyed?)

Both `fork` and `exec` destroy all existing timers created with `timer_create`.

> I nead to find a way to check if one posix timer exist in user mode.

You do that by keeping track of all your timers.

You cannot check whether an arbitrary `timer_t` exists because the C library doesn't maintain a list of timers for you.

Comment: So, how do I check if a posix timer exist or not.  timer_delete will coredump when try to delete a timer that does not exist.

Comment: @user9712902 By keeping track of them.